# Get the last existent sub array depending on parent array position

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, each

How would I make any kind of "for each" to ensure I will get the last existent sub array property. Depending on my object[index] I could have "1 or 10" others "items" sub arrays.

```
object[0].items[0].property(...)
object[1].items[0].items[0].items[0].property(...)
object[2].items[1].items[0].property(...)
object[3].items[1].property(...)
```

Regards,
Rubens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to write a recursive function, that steps through your sub arrays until it hits rock bottom and then return the property.

something like:

```
myRecFunc(obj) {
  if ( obj.items && obj.items.lengh > 0 ) {
    return myRecFunc(obj.items[0]);
  }
  return obj.property;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @philipp-steeger
Do you think is there any way to do that by using jQuery .each() ?